# Jacobson radical subset of maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory

If we define the jacobson radical $J$ to be the intersection of all maximal right ideals then I am trying to show that if we have a maximal two sided ideal $M$ we must have $J\subseteq M$?

Any ideas

Comment: @Vladhagen why must $M$ be in the origional intersection if it only contains maximal right ideals? Need a maximal two-sided ideal be a max right ideal?

Comment: Dear @Vladhagen That hint isn't helpful: in a matrix ring $M_n(F)$ with $n>1$, the zero ideal is a maximal two-sided ideal, but it's not a maximal right ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobson radical of $R$ is the intersection of all right primitive ideals (annihilators of simple right $R$ modules), and every maximal ideal is right primitive.

The equivalence of this definition of the Jacobson radical with the one you gave is pretty easy to prove, and you can find it, for example, in [Martin Isaacs' *Graduate Algebra* starting page 177](http://books.google.com/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=isaacs+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U7iTUpmKI8_aoAS9nYDYDg&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=primitive&f=false).

(If you are wondering why every maximal ideal is right primitive, look at it this way:  every nonzero right $R/M$ module is faithful (why?) and of course every ring with identity has simple right modules via Zorn's Lemma. That would mean $R/M$ is right primitive, and hence $M$ is a right primitive ideal.)

Comment: About "every maximal ideal is right primitive", if $M$ is a maximal two-sided ideal, this does not imply that $M$ is a maximal right ideal. Also, $R/M$ is a simple ring, but that does not imply that $R/M$ is a simple right $R$-module). To find a simple right $R$-module $S$ such that $\text{ann}_R(S)⊆M$, let $M$ be included in a maximal right ideal $L$ by Zorn's Lemma. Then $R/L$ is a simple right $R$ module. Then, $\text{ann}_R(R/L)$ is an ideal containing $M$ and equality follows by the maximality of $M$.

Comment: @AgentSmith The objections you raise --while true-- aren't relevant, because none of the assertions critiqued were intended.  A simple way to see it is that if if $M$ is a maximal two-sided ideal, *every nonzero (left or right) module of $R/M$ is faithful,* and it certainly has simple left and right modules, hence $M$ is both a left and right primitive ideal. I suppose I may as well add this.

Comment: With the correction of $ann_R(S)\subseteq M$ to $ann_R(S)\supseteq M$, I agree with what you wrote as an equivalent way to finding a faithful simple module (since it imples $S$ is $R/M$ faithful.)